# Extract a column from a data.table as a vector, by position

Tags: r, vector, indexing, data.table

How do I extract a column from a data.table as a vector by its position? Below are some code snippets I have tried:

```
DT<-data.table(x=c(1,2),y=c(3,4),z=c(5,6))
DT
#   x y z
#1: 1 3 5
#2: 2 4 6
```

I want to get this output using column position

```
DT$y 
#[1] 3 4
is.vector(DT$y)
#[1] TRUE
```

Other way to get this output using column position

```
DT[,y] 
#[1] 3 4
is.vector(DT[,y])
#[1] TRUE
```

This doesn't give a vector

```
DT[,2,with=FALSE]
#   y
#1: 3
#2: 4
is.vector(DT[,2,with=FALSE])
#[1] FALSE
```

Those two doesn't work:

```
DT$noquote(names(DT)[2]) # Doesn't work
#Error: attempt to apply non-function

DT[,noquote(names(DT)[2])] # Doesn't work
#[1] y
```

And this doesn't give a vector:

```
DT[,noquote(names(DT)[2]),with=FALSE] # Not a vector
#   y
#1: 3
#2: 4
is.vector(DT[,noquote(names(DT)[2]),with=FALSE])
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

A data.table inherits from class `data.frame`. Therefore it is a `list` (of column vectors) internally and can be treated as such.

```
is.list(DT)
#[1] TRUE
```

Fortunately, extracting a vector from a list, i.e. `[[`, is very fast and, in contrast to `[`, package data.table doesn't define a method for it. Thus, you can simply use `[[` to extract by an index:

```
DT[[2]]
#[1] 3 4
```

Comment: Is it possible to maintain the data.table structure rather than convert to a vector? Does this for multiple columns?

Comment: ...and if you wished to subset the data on a specific number of rows alongside a particular column (e.g. in this instance column 2) , you add an additional set of square brackets at the front of the query. That is, if you want the first 10 rows of column 2 then...    DT[1:10][[2]]              Thanks this has made my code much faster!

Answer (score 5):

`DT[,get(names(DT)[colNb])]`

where colNb can be an integer (the desired column number) or a variable containing the column number.