# Can't return the correct value for length() of a column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have read about and taken the DataCamp course on data.table, and am still confused about the behavior of j in data.table[i,j,by]. Specifically, I can't get the data.table to return the correct value of length when I try to index the column by a number (while using `with=FALSE`):

```
library(data.table) lifetech.dt=data.table(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=c(1,2),d=c(5,6,7,8,9)) x=colnames(lifetech.dt) length_counter=NULL

for (a in 1:length(x)){
    length_counter=c(length_counter,length(lifetech.dt[,a, with=FALSE])) } 
length_counter

#should return a length of 5?, instead returns a length of 1
length(lifetech.dt[,a, with=FALSE]) 
length(lifetech.dt[,3,with=FALSE])

#perhaps this way? But it returns 9 (the last value in col. d?
lifetech.dt[.N,d]

#want this, but without having to know the colname of column 4 is "d" is advance 
length(lifetech.dt[,d])
```

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and please [edit] your post.

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible?

Comment: The `length` of a data.frame / data.table is the number of columns, not the number of rows. I believe you're confusing those two things. You probably want `nrow` instead. And note that subsetting like `lifetech.dt[,1, with=FALSE]` returns a data.table while `lifetech.dt[,human_specific_miRBase_ID]` returns an atomic vector (hence, you can run `length` on it and get the number of rows of that column)

Comment: I totally was confusing those. Thanks! Incidentally, how can I pull out a vector instead of a data.table using numerical indeces?

Comment: @geotheory I'll clean this up in a few hours. Don't have a ton of time right now. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to take a single column vector, use `[[` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20043313/1191259 This also works for a single column name (as a string, for which `$` also works, with partial matching like `DT$human_spec`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @frank pointed out in the comments, this question is a duplicate of [The question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043313/extract-a-column-from-a-data-table-as-a-vector-by-position).

Data.table inherits it's class=list status from data.frame, and it can consequently be indexed by [[ instead of [. So,`length(lifetech.dt[[3]])` should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two equivalent solutions to this:

assuming lifetech.dt has a column named 'columnA'

you can do

```
length(lifetech.dt[,columnA,])
```

or

```
nrow(lifetech.dt[,"columnA",with=F])
```

both work on data.table 1.9.6 and R 3.2.2.

So in your case the second solution should work for you!