# Extract a column by reference from a data.table as a vector

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to extract the column values from a `data.table` object specifying the column name using a variable. For example:

```
DT <- data.table(x = c(1, 2), y = c(3, 4), z = c(5, 6))
col <- "z"
```

then

```
> is.vector(DT[, col, with = F])
[1] FALSE
```

because it returns a `data.table` object instead.

I have tried also: `is.vector(DT[, (col), with = F])` and also: `is.vector(DT[, ..col])` with the same result. I have tried other possibilities that produce an error.

Using directly the variable name works:

```
> is.vector(DT[, z])
[1] TRUE
```

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043313/extract-a-column-from-a-data-table-as-a-vector-by-position), that solves it using column position but not using a name by reference:

```
> is.vector(DT[[3]])
[1] TRUE
```

I didn't find an explicit reference about this particular case in the `data.table` [documentation](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html). I am sure it is an easy way to do it, but I didn't find how.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20043412/1412059

Comment: @Roland this solution is by index position, now I realized that for name reference it also works but it was not mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Now I found this solution was addressed by @Frank answer at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617226/referring-to-data-table-columns-by-names-saved-in-variables?rq=1), the question was not specific for this particular problem, but his solution solves my problem too.

Comment: That answer explains how the index solution works. Extraction by column name works exactly the same.

Comment: The first several questions in the FAQ go over the options here (and the FAQ is considered part of the documentation). Type `vignette("datatable-faq")`. (Btw, the FAQ on the website is out of date, I think.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `[[` to extract the column as vector

```
is.vector(DT[[col]])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Now I found this solution was addressed by @Frank answer at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617226/referring-to-data-table-columns-by-names-saved-in-variables?rq=1)