# Use data.table package in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, shinydashboard

I want to use the data.table package in a Shiny App to improve speed. 
However, it's not clear to me how to select the right columns based on the user input.

The following example works for the case when the data is in the data.frame format but not when it is in data.table format.

```
# load packages
library(data.table)
# global  ----------------------------------------
library(shiny)
# use cars dataset
data(cars)
# create datatable from cars data
cars <- as.data.table(cars)

# user interface ---------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    selectInput(inputId = 'col',    label = 'column', choices = names(cars)),
    numericInput(inputId = 'filter',label = 'filter', value = 5)
  ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))

)

# server ----------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {
   output$plot <- renderPlot({
     # filter example
      d1 <- cars[speed>input$filter,]
      x    <- d1[[input$col]]
      hist(x)
   })
}

# run app  --------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043313/extract-a-column-from-a-data-table-as-a-vector-by-position/20043412#20043412

Comment: @Roland, I want to subset by names, not by indices

Comment: Well, list subsetting works just the same with names ...

Comment: works, thanks for your comment. Do you also have a suggestion how to deal with filters based on user inputs (see updated example)?

Comment: hm, typo. Seems to work now