# Select datatable column with variable name

Tags: r, select, datatable

I'm trying to select one column of an R datatable, without much luck:

```
test <- data.table(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), col2 = c(1,2,3,4))
idx  <- 1
test[,idx]
```

The result is `[1] 1` instead of what I assume would be the output of `test[,1]`.

How come?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043313/extract-a-column-from-a-data-table-as-a-vector-by-position/20043412#20043412

Answer (score 1):

We can use the double dots (`..`) to extract the columns saved in an object

```
test[, ..idx]
#   col1
#1:    A
#2:    B
#3:    C
#4:    D
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately: "Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : object '..idx' not found. Any help with that?" Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel What is your data.table version.  It should be updated to new version