# Issues with caret featurePlot on data.table columns

Tags: r, data.table, data-visualization, r-caret, feature-engineering

I am trying to plot a couple of feature columns against the categories for a data.table. However, I am not get color coding by category which happens automatically when a similar formatted iris dataset is plotted.

```
library(data.table)
library(caret)

dtData <- data.table(
  Index = seq(1:9),
  ColumnA = as.numeric(c(1018,1051,979,1036,963,1055,1063,968,1036)),
  ColumnB = as.numeric(c(566,600,529,530,516,586,562,514,537)),
  Category = as.factor(c("hybrid","mountain","road","hybrid","road","mountain","mountain","road","hybrid"))
  )

featurePlot(x=dtData[,2:3],y = dtData[,4], plot="pairs")
```

When I run the code above, I get the following plot:

[image]

It is not colored by category and instead the category also appears as a column which is not as expected. Any pointers on resolving this?

Thanks much.

Comment: Can you try with `y = dtData[[4]]`

Comment: whew.. that seems to be doing the job. But I do not understand why that works and not dtData[,4]. Would still keep the question open for a more elegant solution to the question? Thanks Markus! :)

Comment: Glad it worked. I would not expect a more elegant solution here. The difference is that `dtData[,4]` returns a data.table while `dtData[[4]]` returns a factor, which is what the function expects. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043313/extract-a-column-from-a-data-table-as-a-vector-by-position

Comment: Thanks Markus. One additional question then: is there a better function than featurePlot for plotting datatable feature columns?